# How to write a module declaration that augments another module declaration

Tags: typescript, amd

I am trying to write TypeScript declarations for some existing AMD modules written in JavaScript.

The structure I am trying to represent is a "plugin" model where one module declares an interface and another module extends that interface with "plugins". I am trying to follow the example for module augmentation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but that doesn't seem to allow me to create two separate modules.

Example:

- Module "foo" defines the Foo interface and exports a singleton constant of that interface
- Module "foo-plugin" adds a new "plugin" function to the Foo interface

From the consumer side, I want the behavior to be as follows:

```
// by importing this, I can use the foo singleton as type Foo with only the Foo
// functionality defined in "foo"
import { foo } from "foo";
// by also importing this, I can now use the additional Foo.plugin function defined by "foo-plugin" on the foo singleton
import "foo-plugin";

// this should compile if and only if the "foo-plugin" module is imported
foo.plugin();
```

Is this behavior possible? What would the declarations look like?

Answer (score 0):

I had [the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515196/how-to-augment-module-in-project-scope) with fastify plugin declaration.

```
declare module "foo-plugin" {

    module "foo" {
        function plugin(): void;
    }
}
```