# How to augment module in project scope?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, strong-typing, fastify

I'm using [fastify](https://github.com/fastify/fastify) with plugin [fastify-static](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-static). I also provide my own TypeScript types declaration for this plugin in `typings/fastify-static/index.d.ts`:

```
declare module "fastify-static" {
    import { Plugin } from "fastify";
    import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";

    namespace fastifyStatic {
        const instance: Plugin<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, any>;
    }
    export = fastifyStatic.instance
}
```

Additionally plugin extends fastify `FastifyReply` with method `sendFile`.

When I augment fastify module in module scope like this, works fine:

```
// server.js
import fastify from "fastify";
import fastifyStatic from "fastify-static";

declare module "fastify" {
    interface FastifyReply<HttpResponse> {
        sendFile: (file: string) => FastifyReply<HttpResponse>
    }
}

server.get("/file", async (request, reply) => {
    reply.sendFile('file')
});
```

Unfortunately it works only in this module.
When I move declaration to `typings/fastify-static/index.d.ts` or `typings/fastify/index.d.ts` it override module instead of augment.
**How can I augment `fastify` module in project scope?**

Comment: What do the definitions of `typings/fastify-static/index.d.ts` look like. You need to add the augmentation there

Comment: Its override module instead of augment it. I've edited the question.
Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Titian Cernicova-Dragomir was right. Module augmentation shout be in `typings/fastify-static/index.d.ts`, but not as separate module declaration.

```
// typings/fastify-static/index.d.ts

declare module "fastify-static" {
    import { Plugin } from "fastify";
    import { Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";

    namespace fastifyStatic {
        const instance: Plugin<Server, IncomingMessage, ServerResponse, any>;
    }

    export = fastifyStatic.instance

    module "fastify" {
        interface FastifyReply<HttpResponse> {
            sendFile: (file: string) => FastifyReply<HttpResponse>
        }
    }
}
```